# wp_logout_url($redirect); is not working in wordpress

Tags: plugins, user-registration, logout

I am writing a simple WP plugin that could log the user in and out. As far as login is concerned its working good but I cannot log out, through my plugin. Logout doesn't work after I login. I have tried a lot of suggested solutions but none of them worked.

This is my code:

```
function vrm_loginout(){

    if(is_user_logged_in()){

        echo '<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url($redirect); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>';

        //tried following as well
    //echo '<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( get_permalink() )>" title="Logout">Logout</    a>'; title="Logout">Logout</a>';

    }else{

        wp_login_form();

    }//end of if

}//end of function

add_shortcode('vrm_loginform', 'vrm_loginout');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using PHP tag inside echo statement.

Try this:

```
echo '<a href="'.wp_logout_url().'" title="Logout">Logout</a>';
```

If you want to redirect to any specific url then you can pass it as argument of `wp_logout_url`.

Check [official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_logout_url) of `wp_logout_url`.

**Note :**

It is recommended to return value from the shortcode function rather than directly displaying it. Try `return` instead of printing output by `echo`.